# How to wait for all values in window.performance.timing are defined

Tags: javascript, dom-events, navigation-timing-api

Currently I read the values in `window.performance.timing` within a `window.addEventListener('load', function () {...})` function. however in safari there are values like `loadEventEnd` still being set to `0`.

How to delay my call to `window.performance.timing` in the best way event based until this and other values are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an additional delay in the load event.

```
window.addEventListener('load', check)

function check() {
  if (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].loadEventEnd && other_values()) {
    callToPerformanceTiming()
  }
  else setTimeout(check, 0); //put it back in queue
}
```

As long `loadEventEnd` is `0` the check is repeated.
You can also check `other_values()` to be very shure
it is passed before you do `callToPerformanceTiming()`